# FOLDERID_SkyDrive Not Correctly identifying OneDrive for Business folder

Tags: windows, winapi, onedrive

I am trying to use `FOLDERID_SkyDrive` with `SHGetKnownFolderPath`and the resulting value is `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive` but my one drive for business account is being sync'd to `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive - MyCompany`

Is there a way to get the proper root of the one drive for business?

```cpp
  PWSTR name = nullptr;
  HRESULT hr =
      SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_SkyDrive, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &name);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
   std::wcout << name << std::endl;
   CoTaskMemFree(name);
  }
```

Comment: FOLDERID_SkyDrive represents the one drive personal account associated with the current user, but you can have any number of accounts setup for a given use (there can be more than one "business" account). All defined accounts for the current user are located in the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts` registry key.

Comment: As @Simon, you could read the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts\Business?(? is the index)\UserFolder` to get the path.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT This is going to be reliable going forward across OneDrive and Windows versions? Is this documented anywhere? It would make me feel more comfortable if it was documented somewhere.  When something is undocumented it normally means they will feel free to change it

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I haven't found this in any document but [`this article`] from Nathanaël on forum has metioned about the register.(under the *Registry item* and *Procmon trace*).